# Browse a Rails App with the DB in Sandbox Mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, sandbox

I'm writing a lot of request specs right now, and I'm spending a lot of time building up factories. It's pretty cumbersome to make a change to a factory, run the specs, and see if I forgot about any major dependencies in my data. Over and over and over...

It makes me want to set up some sort of sandboxed environment, where I could browse the site and refresh the database from my factories at will. Has anyone ever done this?

**EDIT:**

I'm running spork and rspec-guard to make this easier, but I still lose a lot of time.

A large part of that time is spent waiting for Capybara/FireFox to spin up. These are request specs, and quite often there are some JavaScript components that need to be exercised as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at a couple of solutions first:

- You can run specific test files rather than the whole suite with something like `rspec spec/request/foo_spec.rb`. You can run a specific test with the `-e` option, or by appending `:lineno` to the filename, where lineno is the line number the test starts on.
- You can use something like [guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec), [watchr](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr), or [autotest](http://rubygems.org/gems/autotest) to automatically run tests when their associated files change.
- Tools like [spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork) and [zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus) can be used to preload the app environment so that test suite runs take less time to run. However, I don't think this will reload factories so they may not apply here.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892937/improve-rails-loading-time/13103714#13103714) for ways that you can improve Rails' boot time. This makes running the suite substantially less painful.

Comment: Hi Chris! I'm doing all 4 of your suggested bullet points; I isolate my individual specs, use spork to preload everything I can, and am running Ruby 2.0. I'm editing my question to provide a little more detail about my environment.

Comment: Have you considered using poltergeist/phantomJS? You could spin up a phantomJS server when you boot your test suite (pre-sporking), which would then be used to run your acceptance tests in. This has the benefit of playing well with CI!